# Error while building FleaFPGA-JTAG-Linux

Tags: compiling, gcc, make, c, ld

I've been trying to compile FleaFPGA-JTAG-Linux for a while now but I keep getting the linker errors:

`cannot find -lftdti1`

`cannot find -lusb-1.0`

When I run `pkg-config --libs --cflags libftdi1` I get :

`-I/usr/config/libftdi1 -I/usr/include/lib-usb1.0 -lftdi1 -lusb-1.0`

On checking whether the .h files exist in the directories above, I can confirm that `ftdi.h` and `usb-1.0.h` indeed live there.

The repo for fleaFPGA-JTAG-Linux can be found here

https://github.com/XarkLabs/FleaFPGA-JTAG/tree/master/FleaFPGA-JTAG-linux

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution. The Makefile comes precpecified with `-m32` as a GCC Flag. Under $CFLAGS.

Deleting this led to smooth compilation. I'm on a 64-bit computer. I assume it means compile for a 32-bit architecture. So it looks for 32-bit .so libs